# How to use user input as filename for save button - Python - tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Have a save button in my GUI, and would like to use users input as file name for saving files.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os


win = Tk()
#main window parameters
win.title(" JEAME ")
win.geometry("900x500")
p1 = PhotoImage(file = 'deltalogo_en.png')
win.iconphoto(False, p1)

def openf():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title="select file",
                                      filetypes=(("JEL files",".jef"), ("All Files","*.*")))
def savef():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir='/', title="select file", initialfile=(),
                                      filetypes=(("JEL files", ".jef"), ("All Files", "*.*")))

#open existing script
btn1 = Button(win, text = ' Open ', command= openf)
btn1.place(x=5, y=5)
#start new script button
btn2 = Button(win, text = ' New ')
btn2.place(x=80, y=5)
#save created script button
btn3 = Button(win, text = ' Save ', command= savef)
btn3.place(x=155, y=5)
#script naming
script_name = Label (
    text = "Script name ").place(x = 10, y = 60)
script_name_input_area: StringVar = StringVar()
Fname = Entry(textvariable=script_name_input_area,
    width = 30).place(x = 100, y = 60)

# Run main loop
win.mainloop()`
```

Users input should be 'script_name_input_area' and after typing anything into this, input should be used for filename after clicking on save button.

Comment: Why could you not find this info on Google? There's surely millions of examples, practically literally.

Comment: @RandomDavis am beginner with Python, but couldnt find single example! Thats why I am asking here... if you can, could you send me link?

Comment: You can't search for an extremely specific combination of things and get results; you have to search for the generic aspects individually. Like, you can search just for how to get user input in Python via a UI and save it to a variable. Or how to save a file with a specific filename. Etc. The information is out there, you just have to combine it in order for it to be helpful. Knowing how to search is extremely crucial as a developer. I'm sure people on here can help, but hopefully these tips help you find the answer before someone here might find it.

Answer (score 1):

To use the user's input from the `script_name_input_area` as the filename when saving a file, you need to modify your `savef` function. Currently, your `savef` function opens a file dialog for saving but doesn't use the input from `script_name_input_area`. Here's how you can modify the `savef` function to use the user's input:

```py
def savef():
    script_name = script_name_input_area.get()
    if script_name:
        file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir='/', title="Select file",
                                         initialfile=script_name,
                                         filetypes=(("JEL files", ".jef"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
```

Here's what's changed in the `savef` function:

1. It retrieves the user's input from `script_name_input_area` using `script_name_input_area.get()`.
2. It checks if the `script_name` is not empty (`if script_name:`) to ensure the user has provided a filename.
3. It uses the `initialfile` parameter of `asksaveasfile` to set the initial filename in the save dialog to the user's input.

Now, when the user types something into the `script_name_input_area` and clicks the "Save" button, the input will be used as the initial filename in the save dialog.